# Slider in angular 6

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and are trying to implement a double slider. I tried follow this sample:

https://angular-slider.github.io/ng5-slider/demos
I add following:

html:

```
<p>Value: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value"></p>
<ng5-slider [(value)]="value" [options]="options"></ng5-slider>
```

And this in my class:

```
import { Ng5SliderModule } from 'ng5-slider';
import { Options } from 'ng5-slider';

 value: number = 100;
 options: Options = {
   floor: 0,
   ceil: 250
 };
```

Error:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
compiler.js:1021
Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'ng5-slider'.
1. If 'ng5-slider' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ng5-slider' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

My question are going to be a little blurry. Normally I would find some kind of bootstrap component and implement that in my html and javascript. But as I understand when working with Angular, you primary work with angular components. Is there something similar for bootstrap for Angular. I looked at Material but it didn't have double slider. Also can anyone recommend something to a get a double slider working?

Comment: Have you added this into your module? Looks like it still needs to be imported

Comment: So you got this working by adding it to the module.ts and the app.config? I'm still getting errors from it with Angular 6: "ng5-slider is not a known element". Any further advise?

Comment: Not the app.config just the module.

Comment: @Steve, for me, in Angular 6, changing [(value)]= to [value]= fixed my run time errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many bootstrap like packages for angular but there is no problem with the one you've picked for double slider.

From the error you've got we can see that you didn't add the Ng5SliderModule to your NgModule:

```
import { Ng5SliderModule } from 'ng5-slider';

...

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
     ...
     Ng5SliderModule,
     ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can see the docs of [ng5-slider git repository](https://github.com/angular-slider/ng5-slider) for more details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I started adding the import you suggest, but it dosen't change the error:( Can it be because I am using Angular 6?

Comment: Got it working thanks to your link. I also need to import it in the module.ts file. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is completely true but be careful that if you use `ng5-slider` in a component that exists in module `custom.module` you must add this line :

```
import { Ng5SliderModule } from 'ng5-slider'
```

to custom.module (not app.module)